# Synchronous Web Browser to String Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

What's the best way to do synchronous navigation to a string with the WPF web browser control?

I know the WebBrowser.NavigateToString(string) does display a string, but it's done asynchronously—not synchronously. On top of that, WebBrowser.NavigateToString always returns a body of null in the WebBrowser.Document area while WebBrowser.Navigate actually returns a body in the document.

In WinForms I could do: WebBrowser.Document.Write(html); but in WPF I can't figure out a good way to do this. I have a function that navigates to a string and returns a value so I do not want to use the WebBrowser.Navigated event...

Comment: Why do you want to do it synchronously?

Comment: So I can return the result (return the innerText) and modify the body. For some reason NavigateToString() always returns a body of null in the document, while Navigate() returns a body (but then I need to save as a temp txt file, then load that in, which is much slower than loading in a string). It's really annoying.

Comment: ..and then once I do that it doesn't load in the full file. I might just end up using the winforms web browser which wouldn't be ideal. I think the WPF browser was a step backwards from what I've seen.

Comment: I see, I've posted my recommendation below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the body first using HttpWebRequest, then process it however you want, before displaying it in the WebBrowser

Comment: But then I still have to navigate synchronously since I can't write out that html to the Web Browser :/

Comment: Wow, I meant to say "navigate Asynchronously" in my last comment. I ended up reverting back to the WinForms WebBrowser to solve my problem.